# Alterar um Select Dropdown para um Text field com Autocomplete

Tags: autocompletar

Bom dia,

Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de alterar uma `Dropdown` com várias opções para uma `Text Field` com a f*unção de autocompletar*.

Meu código para a select `dropdown` é o seguinte:

```
<%= label_tag :aluno_id, "Aluno a ter Disciplina Liberada" %>
<%= select_tag "ofertas[liberacao][aluno_id]", options_for_select(@alunos, { prompt: "Selecione um Aluno" }), { :class => "form-control", :style => "width: 400px;" } %>
```

Comment: Tente  trocar select_tag por datalist_tag veja https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Que linguagem é essa? Use as tags para informar